# Probability of a poker hand contains nothing

Tags: probability

> Suppose we are playing 5 card draw. What is the probability that your hand contains nothing not even a pair?

Thoughts: To have a  worthless hand we need no repeated values, no runs of 5, or not all 5 cards have the same suit.

Let

$A$: no repeated values

$B^c$: no runs of 5

$B$: run of 5

$C^c$: not all 5 cards have the same suit

$C$: all 5 have the same suit

A run of 5 means that we have 5 distinct values. Note a useful property to solve this problem is

$$P(A\cap B^c\cap C^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) + P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

Thus we have $$P(A) = \frac{52\times 48\times 44\times 40\times36}{52\times 51\times 50\times 49\times 48} \approx .51$$

and

$$P(A\cap B) = P(B) = \frac{10\times 4^5}{{52 \choose 5}} \approx .004$$

and

$$P(A\cap B\cap C) = \frac{10\times 4}{{52\choose 5}} \approx .000015$$

I can't seem to figure out $$P(A\cap C) = ?$$

Any suggestions or how I should think about it are greatly appreciated!

Comment: $A\cap C$ is the event of no repeated values and all cards of the same suit. There are $\binom{13}{5}$ ways to draw no repeated values in a particular suit, and there are $\binom 4 1 $ ways to select that suit.$$\mathsf P(A\cap C) =\dfrac{\binom 4 1\binom {13}5}{\binom {52}5}$$ But see Henning Makholm's answer for an easier way to calculate the end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is easier to *count possible hands* than to try to get into probabilities from the beginning.

**Possible sets of ranks.** There are $\binom{13}{5}$ ways to select 5 different ranks for a hand, but 10 of these would be straights, so the actual number of desired assignments is $\binom{13}{5}-10$

**Possible suit assignments.** Once we have chosen the ranks, no matter how we choose them, there are $4^5$ possibilities for which suits they are -- but $4$ of these would be flushes, so we need to subtract them, giving $4^5-4$. (Note that this step is made particularly easy because we already know the ranks are all different, so we never have to worry about using the same card twice).

The number of high-card hands is therefore
$$ ({\textstyle\binom{13}{5}}-10)(4^5-4)  $$
Now divide by $\binom{52}{5}$ to find the probability of such a hand.

Comment: I see have you also included the possible sets of pairs we can have? I did the math and the probability is close to the answer but not exact. From the solutions we have the probability is .501115 and your calculation yields 0.52574491335. Not sure if it really matters I like your approach much better

Comment: @Wolfy: There can be no pairs when we select all five ranks to be different.

Comment: How do you get $0.525\ldots$? I get that $1\,302\,540$ different hands out of $2\,598\,960$ are high-card hands, and $\frac{1302540}{2598960}\approx0.501$.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake in my calculation I am sure your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, which is much slower and clumsier.

There are 52 ways to choose the first card. The second card must be of a different rank, so there are only 48 choices and so on.

So, there are 52*48*44*40*36/5! ways to choose the five cards = 1317888 poker hands with 5 cards all of different ranks. Since  straights, flushes and straights are included in the count , these must all be subtracted from this figure.

The corrrect figure is 1317888-10240-5108-40 = 1302540 .

Henning's solution is definitely far superior.

Answer (score 0):

An even more laborious way to arrive at “nothing” hands.

Arrange the suits according to the customary ranking order in bridge: Spades,
 Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs.

I . Hands with at least one spade:

C(13,4) * (39-12) = 715*27 = 19305 (hands with 4 spades and one card from other suits)

C(13,3) * (39-9) * (30-3) / 2! = 115830 ( 3 spades and 2 cards from other suits )

C(13,2) * (39-6) * (33-3) * (30-3) / 3!= 347490 ( 2 spades and 3 cards from other suits )

C(13,1) * 36 * 33 * 30 * 27 / 4!= 521235 ( 2 spades and 3 cards from other suits )

Total: 1003860 ( A )

II.  Hands with no spades, but at least one heart

C(13,4) * (26-8) = 12870 (hands with 4 hearts and one diamond or club )

C(13,3) * (26-6) * (20-2) / 2! = 51480 ( hands with 3 hearts  )

C(13,2) * (26-4) * (22-2) * (20-2)  / 3!= 102960 ( hands with 2 hearts )

C(13,1) * 24 * 22 * 20 * 18 / 4!= 102960 ( hands with 1 heart )

Total: 270270 ( B )

III. Hands with only diamonds and clubs

C(13,4) * (13-4) = 6435 (hands with 4 diamonds and 1 club )

C(13,3) * C(10,2) = 12870 ( hands with 3 diamonds and 2 clubs )

C(13,2) * C(11,3) = 12870 ( hands with 2 diamonds and 3 clubs )

C(13,1) * C(12,4) = 6435 ( hands with 1 diamond and 4 clubs)

Total: 38610 ( C )

Raw total = A + B + C =1003860 + 270270 + 38610 = 1312740

Since straights are hidden in this calculation, it must be subtracted.

The number of  “nothing” hands : 1312740 – 10200 = 1302540